# Communication between injected iframe and content script -- message passing via background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am injecting an `iframe` in a `tab`. Now inside the the `iframe`, based on user's actions, I need to show some `error/warning/success notifications`. However I want to display these notifications in the `tab` not in `iframe`. So I need to communicate between `iframe` and `content script`. Now these `notifications` are dynamic based on user's actions so I thought of `message passing` between `iframe` and `content script` via `background page`.

So what i have done is send messages from `iframe` to `background`. Now both `background page` and `content script` listens to these messages but only `background page` is able to receive them. On receiving messages it reflects them back to `sender tab`. Now `content script` can receive these messages as they are sent from `background page`.

Now I tried the same using `custom events` but it didn't work.

**But i would like to know any other method which is more efficient than what i am doing??**

**EDIT** : Here's the relevant code

**iframe.js:**

```
    $scope.hideFrame = function(){                                        
       sendMessageToBackground("hideFrame");
    };

     $scope.checkIfFormValid = function(){
       if(!($scope.taskName === "" || $scope.group.selectedGroup === null )){
          $scope.addTask();
        }
        else{
          sendMessageToBackground("invalidForm");
        }
     };

    function sendMessageToBackground(msg){
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: msg});
    }
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
   switch (request.type){

                case "hideFrame":
                   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id,{type:"hideFrame"});
                   break;
                case "invalidForm":
                   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id,{type:"invalidForm"});
                   break;

            }      
 });
```

**content.js:**

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
                switch (request.type){
                     case "invalidForm":
                         var n = noty({
                                        text        : ' Please fill all details',
                                        type        : 'error',
                                        layout      : 'topRight',
                                        timeout     :  10000,
                                        theme       : 'defaultTheme'
                                    });
                        break;

                    case "hideFrame":
                      $("#isolatedFrame").hide();
                      break;
                }      
    });
```

**Using `window.parent.postMessage`(not working)**:

**iframe.js:**

```
 function sendMessageToContent(msg){
             // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: msg});
             window.parent.postMessage({ type: "fromFrame", message: msg }, "*");
            }
```

**content.js:**

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

  if (event.source != window)
    return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "fromFrame")) {
    console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.message);

  }
}, false);
```

Also, when i add a `breakpoint` at `window.parent.postMessage({ type: "fromFrame", message: msg }, "*");` and try to see `window.parent` object , `inspected target` is disconnected. I don't why this is happening??

Comment: As always, post the relevant minimal code (you may also post the link to the extension to test it live).

Comment: @wOxxOm I have added the relevant code

Comment: You haven't posted the code with `custom events` but I suppose it wasn't what should have been used, see [postMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+postMessage+iframe++answers%3A1), there might be a good duplicate because this is a popular task.

Comment: @wOxxOm   I tried window.parent.postMessage but it didn't work. Updated the question. Please check

Comment: Why should it work if `event.source` is the window object of the iframe (because the *source* of the event is an iframe), not of the content script? Also, the inspected target is disconnected because it's a cross-origin iframe.

Comment: @wOxxOm So should i remove that check?

Comment: If you actually want to make it work then I guess yes? :-)

Comment: @wOxxOm it works now. Thanks man

Comment: @ wOxxOm I think 'window.parent.postMessage' is more efficient than what i was doing. Right?

Comment: I would guess so but it's better to perform an actual test: simply add `console.log("iframe")` before `postMessage` and `console.log("content")` in `addEventListener`, then look at the time difference. Repeat for the background method and compare the results.

Comment: Dovnvoting for abusing inline code notation for word highlighing.

Comment: Can you share the manifest file?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a more effective way to achieve it - using `tabs.sendMessage`.

> extensions cannot send messages to content scripts using this method. To send messages to content scripts, use tabs.sendMessage. (see [runtime.sendMessage document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) )

Here's the code.

iframe.js:

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    console.log('greeting:", request.greeting);
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
```

You can also refer to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple for more detail.

**EDIT**

Since `iframe.js` is a content script, you should send the message with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and without using `chrome.tabs` API. Otherwise, `chrome.tabs` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Works! Thanks a ton

Comment: I think OP meant that the website that is loaded in the iframe needs to send the message to the content script, hence `window.parent.postMessage` in his examples